# sympy - find conflicting row in matrix

Tags: python, math, matrix, linear-algebra

I have a matrix `A = Matrix([[1, 0, 0, 20], [-1, 1, 0, 0], [-2, 1, 0, 0], [0, -1, 1, 0]])`, a sympy object.

I want to know if there is a conflicting row - meaning a row that after i reduce the matrix, all the terms in the row are zero, apart from the rightmost one.

This seems easy to do on paper, but I think I misunderstand sympy.
Basically the output from rref method is not what I expected.

Notice that if we row reduce `A` with pen and paper, we should get `Matrix([[1, 0, 0, 20], [0, 1, 0, 20], [0, 0, 0, 20], [0, 0, 1, 20]])` at a certain point.

So row number 2 is a conflicting row.

However when I use `A.rref()` I get something else entirely. I get `Matrix([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]])` and list `<class 'list'>: [0, 1, 2, 3]`

I don't understand how they reached this result and how to interpet the list. How can I find the conflicting rows using sympy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by sympy is correct. The matrix you reached in reducing manually is not the end of the row-reduction process, which explains the difference between your answer and sympy's.

To continue the row-reduction from your matrix, swap rows 2 and 3 (the third and fourth rows), and you get

```
matrix([
 [ 1, 0, 0, 20],
 [ 0, 1, 0, 20],
 [ 0, 0, 1, 20],
 [ 0, 0, 0, 20]])
```

Now subtract row 3 (the last row) from each of the other rows, then divide that last row by 20, and we get

```
matrix([
 [ 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [ 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [ 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [ 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

which is sympy's answer.

There are multiple ways to interpret this result. One way is to think of a system of 4 linear equations in 3 variables--the last column of the matrix hold the constants on the right side of the equations while the other columns are the variable coefficients. Your original matrix represents the equations

```
   x            = 20
-  x + y        =  0
- 2x + y        =  0
     - y + z    =  0
```

and sympy's row reduction shows this system has the same solutions as

```
   x            =  0
       y        =  0
           z    =  0
              0 =  1
```

which, of course, has no solutions at all, thanks to the last equation.

Also, you seem to have a misunderstanding of what row-reduction can do. You ask, "How can I find the conflicting rows using sympy?" and "if there is a conflicting row." Row reduction does not find *which row* conflicts, it finds *if the rows together* conflict. The `rref` process cannot show a conflicting row since it swaps rows if needed to get a non-zero pivot value in proper place, so the rows of the starting and the ending matrix do not correspond. Also, it is not true that one row conflicts with the others, just that all the rows together conflict. In your matrix, you could remove any one of the first 3 rows and the result will be non-conflicting. (Removing the last row still has a conflicting matrix.) So which row can you say conflicts? There usually is not one conflicting row, so `rref()` or any other method cannot possibly find one.